# Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, changelog

I am getting the following liquibase error when I run my Spring Boot application:

***Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.***

Here is the class path in application.yaml:

```
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml
```

I also tried:

```
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml
```

Here is folder structure:

[image]

Changlog master:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <include file="db-changelog-1.0.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: It is a known issue and yet not found a resolve. they advice to use version 3.5

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in v4.4.3

Comment: I still have it on ubuntu v4.4.3. Are you sure?

Comment: still existing on 4.6.1

Comment: Also still existing on 4.9.1

Comment: Still in 4.11.0

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue when putting the changelog files outside the resources folder, but if I include them under *resources/db/changelog*, then it would work fine with setting the bellow config.

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
```

Tested under 4.6.2

Comment: This solution worked for me as well with 4.6.2

Comment: Issue with this is if the file is added to multiple jars with maven-remote-resources for example

Answer (score 3):

This is still an open issue unfortunately. See [2281](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2281).

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/how-liquibase-finds-files.html)

> How the Liquibase classpath worked before version 4.0
>
> Before version 4.0, one of the default locations Liquibase added to
> the classpath was the root directory in your filesystem (/). The
> change caused issues because of a machine-dependent changelog path,
> such as /home/my-user/projects/liquibase/changelog.xml, found under
> the / directory. This way, Liquibase uses the given path as part of
> the changeset identifier stored in the DATABASECHANGELOG table, and
> when you run Liquibase from
> /home/other-user/projects/liquibase/changelog.xml, Liquibase sees it
> as a different changelog and tries to rerun all the previously run
> changesets.
>
> To prevent identification issues from happening, a / was removed as a
> default part of the classpath. How the Liquibase classpath works in
> 4.0 and later versions
>
> Starting with Liquibase 4.0, the root directory (/) is no longer a
> default part of the classpath because of the issue mentioned in the
> previous section.
>
> ...

The message "Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter." refers to the root directory '/', and does not mean to add a slash to the start of your classpath path. Afaik, `classpath:x` and `classpath:/x` are the same.

Also, the message appears when the master changelog is not found, for whatever reason, so also a typo can cause this message. It's only a hint telling you that it might not be found because the file is not on the classpath, because they removed the root directory from the classpath, but it could also not be found because you specified the wrong path (I just did that).

To configure it correctly, the master changelog must be on the Liquibase classpath. In Spring Boot, the Liquibase classpath is set to the application's classpath, i.e. you can use `src/main/resources`.

Tl;dr: When your file is `src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml` use
`spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`

I don't know, whether there was or is a bug in regards to that with certain Liquibase versions, but that's how it's *supposed* to work, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to remove "classpath:" from "change-log:" parameter.
Also try to check your pom.xml ("changeLogFile" tag in configuration):
there should not be a "${basedir}" before change log file path.

```
<changeLogFile>
  /src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog.xml
</changeLogFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. In my case, I found out we have a resource filtering maven plugin configured in pom.xml and the Liquibase SQL changelog file was not included.

The below code worked for me

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.sql</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem under *IntelliJ* with `spring-boot 2.7.9` dependency during integration tests ran through the IDE.
But oddly, not when running these tests with *Maven* directly, on the command line.

Whatever, I changed the spring-boot dependency to `spring-boot 2.7.14` and it solved my problem.